# How to test an Error of a Method in a Vue.js Component using jest

Tags: vue.js, testing, methods, jestjs, components

How can I test the method `createUser()` of my Vue component? I want to test if the `createUser()` method throws an *Error* if the `firstname < 2` for example. How is this possible?

I'm not really familiar with testing VUE components. It's my first time, so I have no idea how to get access the VUE component and how to submit for a example a username to the component

```
<script>
import {ApiService} from '../ApiService.js';
import {User} from '../User.js';

//const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080';
const apiService = new ApiService();

export default {
    name: "CreateUser",

    data() {
        return {
            input: {
                username: "",
                firstname: "",
                lastname: "",
                title: "",
                password: "",
                groupId: "",
                groups: [],
            },
        }
    },

    /.../

    methods: {

        getAllGroups() {
            apiService.getAllGroups().then((data) => {
                this.input.groups = data;
            });
        },

        createUser() {

            if (this.input.firstname == null || this.input.firstname.length < 2 || this.input.firstname > 50) {
                throw ("Firstname to short/long/empty");
            } else {
                let user = new User(this.input.username, this.input.lastname, this.input.title, this.input.firstname, this.input.password, this.input.groupId)

                apiService.createUser(user).then(() => {
                    location.reload()
                });
            }
        },
```

**I tried the following, but something doesn't not work**

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import UserModal from "../src/views/UserModal";

describe('UsarModal', () => {
    it('should throw error when first name is too short', () => {

        const myItems = [
            {
            username: "Heinz",
            firstname: "H",
            lasname: "Müller"}
        ]

        const wrapper = shallowMount(UserModal, {
            input: {
                myItems
            }
        })

        expect(wrapper.vm.createUser()).toThrow("Firstname to short/long/empty")
    })
})
```

Comment: Code formatting and grammatical revision.

Answer (score 2):

since in the code, it is throwing an error, so we will need to add a catch block in our test case to test this scenario. PFB example for your case:

```
try {
    wrapper.vm.createUser();
  } catch (error) {
    expect(error).toBe('Firstname to short/long/empty');
  }
```

let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you did in your example is very close. You just need to wrap the function call that is going to throw the exception in a lambda, e.g.

```
        expect(() => wrapper.vm.createUser()).toThrow("Firstname to short/long/empty")
```

As described in the docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror

It's probably doing something like internally wrapping the lambda in a try/catch, but I think using this method is a bit nicer than wrapping in a try/catch in your own test.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip! But still something is not working right. It seems for me, that it does not accept my mock-data for input. I want to test if a got an error when I use a username which is too short. But even when I put a username that's long enough, the try catch block catches my error as you can see in the attached picture.

```
import {shallowMount} from '@vue/test-utils'
import UserModal from "./UserModal";

describe('ParentComponent', () => {
test("displays 'Emitted!' when custom event is emitted", () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(UserModal, {
                input: {
                    username: "asfsf",
                    firstname: "thomas",
                    lastname: "bird",
                    title: "Dr.",
                    password: "asdasda",
                    groupId: "2",
                    groups: [],}

    });

    try {
        wrapper.vm.createUser();
    } catch (error) {
        expect(error).toBe("username missing");
    }
})
});
```

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A1yY.png)